# Ng2 redux-store for Ionic 2 + Angular 2

Tags: angular, redux, ionic2

Can we use ng2-redux-store [(Github)](https://github.com/angular-redux/store) web App development setup (store, action, reducer, subscribe etc...) in ionic 2 for angular 2 HYBRID app development. I cant find any QA for ng2-redux-store for ionic 2 app.

Same question raised in ionic forum also [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ng2-redux-store-for-ionic-2-angular-2/92662)

Thanks to all

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

We are currently developing a hybrid app using Ionic 2, Cordova and ng2-redux-store. At the moment we are in the beginning of the project so I don't have any opinion yet but technically it works.